# Custom claims not appearing in User Profile of WSO2 API Manager

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am new to `WSO2 API Manager (APIM)` using version `1.9.0`. I'm looking to developed a functionality of JWT using OpenId in WSO2 APIM. So I created `Service Provider (SP)` named as `"test"` and created `OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration` also. Now when I created few custom claims in `"Available Claim Dialects"` under **http://schema.openid.net/2007/05/claims** (`Home ->Configure ->Claim Management ->Claim View`) I don't see those claims are getting populated in User Profile section why?

Instead if I created those claims `Available Claim Dialects` section named as **http://wso2.org/claims**, then only it's getting visible in user's `User Profile` section. Because of these reason we can't see any claim dialect in `X-JWT-Assertion`

Could anyone please explain the possible reason of failure ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not see custom claims under user profile, instead of it shows only the default claim dialect http://wso2.org/claims.
If you want a custom dialect and claims, create it and map them to default dialect.